# javascript getElementById.label.style

Tags: javascript, css, label

This is not working for me, and by not working I mean it will not display none on the label....

```
document.getElementById('clubname').label.style.display = 'none';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have no idea...I am very new to this

Comment: Does #clubname have an attribute label?

Answer (score 1):

[Labelable elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/forms.html#category-label) can have multiple labels, so the elements have a [`labels` property](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-label-element.html#dom-lfe-labels) not a `label` property.

But I don't know what the level of browser support is for this property currently.

Answer (score 1):

To decypher what you have:

```
document.getElementById('clubname')
```

will attempt to return an element with the id "clubname". If no such element exists, it will return `null`.

```
.label
```

will attempt to access the `label` property of the object returned above. If that was `null`, an error will be thrown.

```
.style
```

will attempt to access the `style` property of whatever was returned above. If that value was not an object (or not convertable to an object) like `null` or `undefined` then it will throw an error.

```
.display = 'none';
```

will either access or assign a `display` property of the object returned previously and assign it a value of `'none'`.

In HTML5, there is a category of [labelable elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#category-label) that have a `labels` property that references a NodeList of their associated labels. So what the above might do (if it completes without error and accessed a single member of the related labels NodeList, e.g. `...labels[0].style...`) is hide the related label. If the element is a child of the label (which they frequently are) it will hide the element too.

But the `labels` property is not widely implemented yet.

Does that help?

Anyhow, a safer way to do what you want is:

```
// First attempt to get a reference to the element
var el = document.getElementById('clubname');

// If the above returned an element, and it has a labels property
// and that property has at least one member
if (el && el.labels && el.labels[0]) {

    // Safe to assume el.labels[0] is a DOM element, so
    // mess with its style object
    el.labels[0].style.display = 'none';
```